# Is there any way to translate the language from English to Arabic in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have an application built in AngularJS. I need to change the language from English to Arabic.

Is there any plugin to do this automatically that can change all my views from English to Arabic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plugins are not available to translate from one language to another. Angular's internationalization (i18n) tools help make your app available in multiple languages.

https://angular-translate.github.io/

Comment: Does it support Arabic?

Comment: It supports all the languages if you do internationalization